# CodeActivity InArgument<T> accessing values of T

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a bit of a twist that is a little more trouble than I thought it would be. Normally I would have an InArgument and use it as below:

```
public InArgument<Int32> XYZ_ID { get; set; }
public InArgument<Int32> XYZ_COUNT { get; set; }

protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(...)
{
....snip....
_ABC_ID = XYZ_ID.Get(context),
_ABC_Count = XYZ_COUNT.Get(context)
```

This works great and I thought a custom object we be close to the same process but I can't seem to figure it out. ActvUsrPrgmResults is just a class of properties such as AccountName, FirstName etc. So I passed it in like any other type.

```
public InArgument<bool> IsHappy { get; set; }
public InArgument<bool> IsClapping { get; set; }
public InArgument<ActvUsrPrgmResults> itm_ActvUsrPrgm { get; set; }
```

Accessing it though is a bit more difficult....for me.

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    NewPerson x = new NewPerson
    {
        AccountName = this.itm_ActvUsrPrgm.Get(?????
        //this doesn't work either
        AccountName = itm_ActvUsrPrgm.?????
```

In other words I can't see how to access the properties of the itm_ActvUsrPrgm InArgument.

Thank You for any help or direction
JB

### Additional Info

I have this CodeActivity in a ForEach (List). So each item in the generic collection is a single instance of ActvUsrPrgmResults. So I hand this off to my CodeActivity thinking I will have a handle to manipulate that item's data????

### Interesting

Now based upon Will's comments I got to thinking about this slight of hand. It works but shouldn't there be a more elegant approach?

```
public InArgument<bool> IsHappy { get; set; }
public InArgument<bool> IsClapping { get; set; }
public InArgument<ActvUsrPrgmResults> itm_ActvUsrPrgm { get; set; }

protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    ActvUsrPrgmResults y = itm_ActvUsrPrgm.Get(context);
    NewPerson x = new NewPerson
    {
        AccountName = y.AccountName....
```

Comment: Before anything, you should read the framework design guidelines.  Why are the properties of ActvUsrPrgmResults InArguments?  Are they set by binding within the workflow?  Typically, non-activity types should be serializable POCOs.  Only properties you bind to other properties within the Workflow should be In/Out/InOutArguments.  This is because the workflow has to know about these Arguments, which is accomplished during a call to CacheMetadata (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivitymetadata.addargument.aspx)

Comment: Fair enough. I'm likely doing it wrong. I have a ForEach<T> that this CodeActivity is in. I want to get the values from the current item and do some fancy stuff to them. So I have assigned the item to the InArgument thinking I could then have a handle inside the CodeActivity.

Comment: I don't use code activities (my base is always a NativeActivity), but it should be easy to test.  Convert ActvUsrPrgmResults properties into POCO properties, mark it and all types it references [Serializable] (eh, this is paranoia, as it only matters when the workflow is idled and unloaded), and try again.  If it works, I'll convert this into an answer.

Comment: By converting to POCO I assume you mean public ActvUsrPrgmExrcsResults itm_ActvUsrPrgm { get; set; } which works great but now I'm not sure how to assign a val from the workflow. i.e. how to get the item from the ForEach<T> handle.

Comment: Which is why I didn't answer.  I'm not sure *what* the heck you're trying to do.  Another possible solution:  Bind an InArgument on your CodeActivity (or create a NativeActivity if you can't do this on a CodeActivity) that binds to the item of the ForEach<T>.

Comment: Will you got me running down the right path. If you post one of your comments I'll up mark it as you deserve credit for getting me thinking clearly.

Comment: Hey, no problems.  In future, you might want to isolate *exactly what you're trying to do* in a prototype.  Helps clear out all the confusion and helps when you're still stuck and need to ask a question.  I've got probably 50 WF4 prototypes by this point.  Also created a [project template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99aa1efc-3409-44fc-8e72-9b0bb62515eb) that speeds up the process.  You might find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is me, myself, and I. I wasn't getting a handle on the object being passed in. For some under the covers reason an "InArgument" is not immediately accessible until you get a firm grasp on the exact object from the given context. I don't know for sure but I suspect this is due to multiple workflows running so you can't just grab any ole object ytou must get the object from the proper context. Anyway here are my comments of what I learned inline.

```
public InArgument<bool> IsHappy { get; set; } //bool variable being passed in
public InArgument<bool> IsClapping { get; set; } //bool variable being passed in
public InArgument<ActvUsrPrgmResults> itm_ActvUsrPrgm { get; set; } //custom object being passed in

protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    bool Happy = context.GetValue(this.IsHappy);
    bool Clap = context.GetValue_this.IsClapping);
    ActvUsrPrgmResults y = context.GetValue(this.itm_ActvUsrPrgm);
    //NOW!!! we have a handle to the proper objects for this context

    //This also works. I just flip flopped the InArgument property and the context.
    ActvUsrPrgmResults y = itm_ActvUsrPrgm.Get(context);

    NewPerson x = new NewPerson
    { 
        AccountName = y.AccountName....
```